# Where does Firefox store its Bookmarks locally?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, user-data

I need to parse Firefox' bookmarks programmatically and am looking for the bookmarks.

On OS X Firefox stores the (default) profile data in `~/Application Support/Profiles/[abcdefgh].default/`

There's a folder called `bookmarkbackups` but it doesn't seem to contain the current bookmarks.

So where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it myself. Inside the profile folder `~/Application Support/Profiles/[abcdefgh].default/` the bookmarks and a lot more are stored in a sqlite database called `places.sqlite`.

This is a EDR of it:

[image]